# Are the built-in integration tests run concurrently or sequentially?

Tags: rust

I am writing integration tests to work with a database. In the start of each test, I clear the storage and create some data.

I want my tests to run sequentially to ensure that I am working with an empty database. But it seems that integration tests are run concurrently because sometimes I get existing documents after cleaning the database.

I checked the database and found that the documents created in different tests have approximately the same creation time, even when I'm adding a delay for each test (with `std::thread::sleep_ms(10000)`).

Can you clarify how the integration tests are run and is it possible run them in order?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The built-in testing framework runs concurrently by default. It is designed to offer useful but simple support for testing, that covers many needs, and a lot of functionality can/*should* be tested with each test independent of the others. (Being independent means they can be run in parallel.)

That said, it does listen to the `RUST_TEST_THREADS` environment variable, e.g. `RUST_TEST_THREADS=1 cargo test` will run tests on a single thread. However, if you want this functionality for your tests always, you may be interested in not using `#[test]`, or, at least, not directly.

The most flexible way is via `cargo`'s support for tests that completely define their own framework, via something like the following in your `Cargo.toml`:

```
[[test]]
name = "foo"
harness = false
```

With that, `cargo test` will compile and run `tests/foo.rs` as a binary. This can then ensure that operations are sequenced/reset appropriately.

Alternatively, maybe a framework like [`stainless`](https://github.com/reem/stainless) has the functionality you need. (I've not used it so I'm not sure.)

Comment: Another use case for disabling concurrency is when tests are run inside a debugger.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to an env var is the [`--test-threads`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/cargo/commands/cargo-test.html) flag. Set it to a single thread to run your tests sequentially.

```
cargo test -- --test-threads 1
```